# React Native: how do I add a file to "Xcode project root"?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-onesignal

I'm following [this guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-sounds#2-add-sound-files-to-app) to add custom push notification sounds to my React Native project. It says to take my `.wav` file and `Add files to the Xcode project root. Make sure Add to targets is selected when adding files so that they are automatically add to the bundle resources`. Can anyone explain exactly how to do this? Do I drag and drop the file to a specific spot in the file structure in XCode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If you drag and drop your `.wav` file under your main project folder (where `Info.plist` is) then you'll be able to access this file in Javascript like this:

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const fileName = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/yourFile.wav`
```

Check if it exists:

```
const exists = await RNFS.exists(fileName);
```